SAPUI5 tinymce table column resize not resizing
When I upgraded my sapui5 version to 1.120.12 the tinymce table columns resize is not working anymore.
This the setting I have use:
window.tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mainApp---test--myContainer',
        inline: true,
        table_resize_bars: true,
        plugins: [ "table"],
});

the resize still working in sapuit version 1.115.1 the issue was introduce with 1.116. I have googled apparently this is not a known issue.

If anyone encountered the same issue,
this is because sapui5 ver 1.116 has an update in the sap.tnt library which update the zIndex. The content of my pages where under those, thus its hindering with the defaults of tinymce's
